# How to use TObjectList for arbitrary class type?

Tags: delphi, generics, inheritance, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm still a bit fuzzy with generics in Delphi, but have been using `TObjectList<>` quite widely. Now I have a situation where I have a base class with such a private field, but needs to be created for an arbitrary class, also inherited from another base.

To clarify, I have two base classes:

```
type
  TItem = class;
  TItems = class;

  TItemClass = class of TItem;

  TItem = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FSomeStuffForAllIneritedClasses: TSomeStuff;
  end;

  TItems = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FItems: TObjectList<TItem>;
    FItemClass: TItemClass;
  public
    constructor Create(AItemClass: TItemClass);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Add: TItem;
    ...
  end;
```

This pair of classes is then further inherited into more specific classes. I'd like the object list to be shared for all of them, while each holds actually a different type internally.

```
type
  TSomeItem = class(TItem)
  private
    FSomeOtherStuff: TSomeOtherStuff;
    ...
  end;

  TSomeItems = class(TItems)
  public
    function Add: TSomeItem; //Calls inherited, similar to a TCollection
    procedure DoSomethingOnlyThisClassShouldDo;
    ...
  end;
```

Now the problem is when it comes to creating the actual object list. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
constructor TItems.Create(AItemClass: TItemClass);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FItemClass:= AItemClass;
  FItems:= TObjectList<AItemClass>.Create(True);
end;
```

However, the code insight complains about this:

> Undeclared Identifier `AItemClass`

Even more, the compiler has yet a different complaint:

> Undeclared Identifier `TObjectList`

Where, I do in fact have `System.Generics.Collections` used in this unit.

What am I doing wrong here, and how should I do this instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `TItems` generic:

```
TItems<T: TItem, constructor> = class(TPersistent)
private
  FItems: TObjectList<T>;
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  function Add: T;
  ...
end;

constructor TItems.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FItems:= TObjectList<T>.Create(True);
end;

function TItems<T>.Add: T;
begin
  Result := T.Create;
  FItems.Add(Result);
end;
```

If you inherit, simply put the correct generic parameter:

```
TSomeItems = class(TItems<TSomeItem>)
public
  procedure DoSomethingOnlyThisClassShouldDo;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: See, I knew there had to be another way using generics. Let me give this a shot (when I get a chance).

Comment: Of course it is worth stating that this requires the item type to be known at compile time, which is sometimes not the case.

Answer (score 2):

The `TObjectList` is not meant to be used in that manner. The fact that it was originally defined as `TObjectList<TItem>` means that it will expect you to create it this way as well. It needs to be defined with the precise class you intend to create it as.

Instead, just create it with `TItem`, and then whenever you create a new item which is supposed to be added to this list, *then* you create it using the class type. Any time you need to access the items in this list, just cast them on the fly.

For example...

```
Result:= FItemClass.Create;
FItems.Add(Result);
```

...can be the contents of your `Add` function.

Comment: You are going to want a virtual constructor to make this work in the long run

Comment: @David Indeed, but I left all that out as it's not related to the question.

Comment: Not directly, but it's absolutely the next hurdle that anybody doing this will face. Which is why I left a helpful comment.